# Trying to filter a with_item results in ansible

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2, docker-image

Ho folks. I've tried to find a working answer fothis but failed; 
We're loading docker image sinto a vm. We'd like to debug out the list of `.actions` of each, without hard-coding the response list.
Does anyone know how?

here's our code so far:

```
---
- name: 'Debbug images to pull'
  debug:
    var: required_images

- name: 'Pull docker images so that we have them pre-loaded'
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ item.image_name }}:{{ item.image_version }}"
    state: 'present'
  with_items: "{{ required_images }}"
  register: docker_pull_output

- name: 'Confirm images pulled attempt a - this looks righ tbut has the array length hard coded'
  debug:
    var: item
    verbosity: 2
  with_items:
   - "{{ docker_pull_output.results[0].actions }}"
   - "{{ docker_pull_output.results[1].actions }}"
   - "{{ docker_pull_output.results[2].actions }}"
   - "{{ docker_pull_output.results[3].actions }}"
   - "{{ docker_pull_output.results[4].actions }}"

- name: 'Confirm images pulled attempt b - this spams us with the full item, not just the .action property'
  debug:
    var: item.actions
    verbosity: 2
  with_items: "{{ docker_pull_output.results }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all actions from your pull task, you can use [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/):

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ docker_pull_output.results | json_query('[].actions[]') }}"
```